# How to remove elements of one map from another map?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

```
HashMap<String, String> foo = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> baar = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

How to remove items found in `baar` from `foo`?

Comment: Do you want to remove any entries where the key is found in baar, or does the value have to be the same as well? E.g. if foo has ("apple", "pie") and baar has ("apple", "cobbler"), should apple pie be removed from foo? Also, have you tried to solve this on your own at all? What have you tried, and in what way did it not work?

Comment: It's not clear enough. What's the relationship between baar and foo?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try:

```
foo.keySet().removeAll(baar.keySet())
```

Changes to a `Map`'s [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) are reflected in the map itself.

If you want to remove *exact* mappings (not just based on keys), you can use the same approach with the [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) instead:

```
foo.entrySet().removeAll(baar.entrySet());
```